# TLS 1.2 IIS hosted ssl sends reply 403.7 to Firefox but 200 to Postman on one server

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, hosting

I have an issue with IIS on Windows Server 2019 and TLS 1.2.

I replaced the ROOT CA, and there are new installed trusted root certificates.

Now on `IIS` i have some sites that `require ssl` is set to true.

Now there are two scenarios using Firefox:

A GET on any site that requires TLS and **from client** (Firefox) **send certificate that is issued by OLD ROOT CA** and is still valid and `http200` /ok.

BUT

If **from client** (Firefox / Chrome etc is the same) send cert that is issued by NEW ROOT CA (valid also)
i  receive a 403.7 from the server. (not see this in browser, it just asks again for certificate)
[image]

I don't know why it shows 12s here. Response is instant and ON CLIENT i do not see 403.7, i see connection reset?

[image]

How to try debug more?

**and also strangest thing :**

If i do same get with same certificate issued by new root CA, but from postman, i receive a 200/ok
how to find out why?

**and second strangest thing :**

If i host same site that `require ssl` on other Windows Server 2019 server, it is OK with both certificates.

SO IT IS THIS ONE SERVER ISSUE WITH NEW CERTS CA / ISSUER.

----edit------

**one more strange thing :**

If I do same get but from server, via server IP or localhost, and send SAME new certificate, it is ok.

So ONLY when we go from REMOTE pc browser there is this issue, so I'm thinking about some netsh issues?

No idea whats more to check.

and also

No new root ca is installed on both machines or client or server, and visible in mmc>certs machine trusted root ca in intermediate also ok etc.

On IIS is configured only ssl cert for https binding that matches the endpoint url, issued by new/old root CA no difference - connection reset from browser and ok from postman.    And also if I import this new CLIENT certificate ON the server so I can check chain, the certificate  chain ok and trusted.

IMHO if it works from localhost with the same client certificate, then IIS settings are 100% ok, so it must be something else?   maybe something with netsh ? checked also and is the same as on second machine that works fine.

Please advice what's more to check or where can be the issue?

Comment: When asking about "it must be something else", people usually draw out the network topology and start to capture SSL/TLS handshake packets at different spots (not only the client machine).

Comment: yes i did and postman sends cert imidietly , browser must ger 'cert request' but it get it and send correctly , but not at 'first hit' as postman is configuret but after request as it is browser and browser does not send untill have request

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where a CA would be replaced in such a slipshod fashion when the usage is non-typical in this way.

Comment: please say more? old expired so had to be new ? what is unusual in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also replaced the certs on the sites with new root ca. When changing the root ca, the whole certificate chain changes so the certificates itself also need to reflect that

For testing i would issue a new certificate from the new root ca and import that to the ssl binding of the sites involved. Also make sure to clear the browser cache and restart iis after changing the certificates

Another more complex option would be to export the current certificate, and open as a text file, decode it, and see if the new root ca is in there

Comment: certs are all ok / it works with them from postman and from other host also , if it would be cert issue then it would not work. it is something about being able to use this new cert when browser asks / get cert request from server. postman does not get cert request as it sends it in  'first hint' as it is configuret that way, as i wrote On IIS is configured only ssl cert for https binding that matches the endpoint url, issued by new/old root CA no difference

Comment: Sounds like an issue on the client. You could try to install the new root ca certificate manually in the Trusted Root ca store of the client and then test

Comment: client have it installed and it is ok. postman is ok. browser - i had to add cert manualy to browser-user store so it asks on trying to get when server requre - i can chose in browser witch to send. and if i send new then asks again , if send old then is 200 ok.  from postman is ok with both new and old...

Comment: Yeah it looks like you have client cert validation enabled for those sites

Comment: nope and even if - it is same site thats works from the same client pc just from postman. from browser no , same cert...